# Restrict access from another user to the NTFS partition

Tags: ntfs, users, accounts

It is possible somehow restrict access to a partition to a specific user in Ubuntu? I am using Ubuntu x64 11.10, I made 2 accounts, both accounts belong to the Administrators group. And I have 3 partitions, on first is OS formatted in ext4, the second one is swap, and the third one is partition designed for data storage, formatted in NTFS, now I want to restrict access to the third one for second user, or hide it. And by the way, the NTFS partition is set to mount automatically at start up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a group called ntfs. Then edit the group to add all of the users that you want to be able to access the ntfs partition.

```
sudo addgroup <groupname> ( ntfs )
```

Then

```
    sudo chgrp ntfs /media/disk (ntfs )
    sudo chmod 770 /media/disk (ntfs )
```

> To add a new user to a existing group you would do this:

```
sudo adduser  (username)  ntfs
```

For More Detail plz have look

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1100120

Comment: The solution has no changes :), the disk is still accessible from second user

Comment: add details and update your ?

Comment: which details? the ntfs partition is still accessible, I made all the steps which you described below