# Restrict access to my home folder from another standard user account

Tags: permissions, users, ntfs, home-directory

I have made a new user on my machine to be used by my family.

But when I logged in to the family account which is not an administrative account, I could access my home folder(which is an administrative account).

I want to restrict the access to my home folder from the new standard user...How do I do this??

And I would also like to restrict that user from using the other NTFS partitions I have.

In short that account should have access only to its own home folder and not to my home folder or to any NTFS partition present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be logging in as your user, open up a terminal (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), type

```
chmod go-rwx ~
```

and hit enter.

Like that you deny the permission to read, write and cd to your home directory to anybody apart from you.

Comment: That has worked..!! thanx..!! any idea about restricting the permission to the NTFS partition??

Comment: @Nirmik See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100698/restrict-access-from-another-user-to-the-ntfs-partition?rq=1) for restricting access to NTFS partition.

Comment: this did the job for ntfs also !