# How do I prevent one user in particular from accessing my home directory?

Tags: permissions

There's a specific user that I don't want to be able to access my home directory. How do I deny access to them, while still allowing access to others who would normally have it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict acces to my home folder from another standard user account](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141130/restrict-acces-to-my-home-folder-from-another-standard-user-account)

Comment: IMO the best way is with encryption - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory. If you want to have a finer grain of control you need to use ACL - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs and

Comment: @user68186 (and others)  It may not be a duplicate as Rob may want to restrict only one user and not all users.

Comment: Thanks @bodhi.zazen for pointing this out. I will retract my close vote, but keep the link in comment, in case someone is looking for a more general solution.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Encryption and ACLs solve two completely different issues. Encryption may be worth a mention here, but it's not a solution.

Comment: Please remove the close votes --- the question is NOT a duplicate; OP was asking to restricting access to just one user, which is not solved in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @BlacklightShining - I would not say they are completely different issues, they are different tools to restrict access with advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen They restrict access at different levels, one of which is not applicable here. Encrypting your home directory won't prevent other users on the system from accessing it when it's mounted; restrictive permissions on the mountpoint (or a parent directory) will.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to limit access to users outside of your group or any other user, the question is a duplicate of [Restrict access to my home folder from another standard user account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141130/restrict-acces-to-my-home-folder-from-another-standard-user-account)

Otherwise, if you want to restrict access to **just one user**, call it `enemyuser`, use [ACL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs):

```
cd ~
setfacl -m u:enemyuser:000 .
```

...and just `enemyuser` will have the access to your home directory denied.

To check the effect:

```
[romano@pern:~] % chacl -l .
. [u::rwx,u:enemyuser:---,g::r-x,m::r-x,o::r-x]
```

To remove the ACL, you just say:

```
setfacl -x u:enemyuser .
```

The `*acl` commands used here are from the package `acl`, which should be installed by default (at least, I think).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exacly what I wanted. In case I change my mind and I need to allow enemyuser access, what do I need to do?

Comment: To remove the ACL, replace the `-m` with `-x`.

Comment: On my system, the command `lsacl` does not exist. Where did you get it?

Comment: @PaddyLandau oops, it's a script I got from internet some time ago that pretty-prints long ACL lists. I changed the answer using standard tools. Here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2014-10/msg00031.html