# How to deny drive access to other users in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: permissions

In my system I have two users and 2 drive partition like (A and B). I have my files in "A" drive. If other user log into my system. I need to deny access to "A" drive only and "B" drive should be common access.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/609194/restricting-a-specific-user-from-accessing-my-home-in-linux/609201#609201

Answer (score -2):

I guess this manual page may help you:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

If some more sophisticated scenarios are required at some stage - ACL's may also be useful:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

Long story short - proper file permissions will help you.

Comment: Well - I'd assume (I know, assumptions are very risky) that people can read manuals and Ubuntu is a business/organization serious enough to keep their helps in proper order, with redirects to newer versions if necessary.