# No permission to /var/www/ folder even though root

Tags: permissions, apache2, root

I am currently trying to modify the content of `/var/www/mywebsite` via sftp with my user "exampleadmin" which has root permissions and is in the group "root".

When I try to add a file or directory via SFTP I receive the error message: `permission denied`. As of now I am not fully understanding why since my user should have root access.

I listed the folder content of `/var/www` with the command `ls -la` and got the following results:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 May  6 10:00 .  
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 May  6 07:59 ..  
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May  6 09:49 html  
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  6 10:00 mywebpage
```

Now I have several questions about the permissions that I could not find answers to yet:

- If I change the owner or group of the folders/files, will the "root" owner/group be removed, meaning they have no further access?
- Is it possible to allow multiple groups and/or users specific permissions such as in Windows or can I only assign a single owner and a single group?
- What If I want to have the following setup:

  - user 1 with full access
  - user 2 with read/execute
  - user 3 with deny
  - other read-only

If this is the case, there must be a best practice for setting up apache file permissions on a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache and similar server programs are usually not run by the `root` user since this could lead to a security leak if they contained a bug.

It is [recommended for web pages](https://askubuntu.com/a/493401/250300) (that are not modified by Apache) to be owned by `root` and have the read permissions for everyone but it does not allow the server to *modify* the contents.

Apache is usually run under the user `www-data`. To allow write access to your `/var/www`, you should change the ownership of the relevant data. You should limit the access to the folders you really need to modify using the server.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/<relevant subfolder>
```

To your particular questions:

> If I change the owner or group of the folders/files, will the "root" owner/group be removed, meaning they have no further access?

As long as you keep the read permissions for everyone, everyone can read them. The ownership by `root` is generally the most restrictive one.

> Is it possible to allow multiple groups and/or users specific permissions such as in Windows or can I only assign a single owner and a single group?

If you need multiple users to have specific permissions, you have to create a group for them in Linux.

> What If I want to have the following setup: …

This is a very specific setup and you should [ask another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) if it’s not just a theoretical problem. You might want to get some information about [ACL](https://askubuntu.com/a/609201/250300) first.