# SETFACL to not go out of /home

Tags: permissions, shared-folders, acl

So I've been testing ACL's in Linux and they work as intended. I have, for example, this folder where I've stablished permissions for users belonging to the gruop `share`. So far, so good...

```
lucas@lucas:/$ getfacl testAcl/
# file: testAcl/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:share:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:share:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

This works fine. Once the ACL has been set, users can or cannot go into the specified folder, as per their group membership.

But I'm interested in something a little different: users usually log into the server, and they land in their `/home/user` folder. How can I set up an ACL so users can't leave the `/home` directory but also be able to go deeper inside `/home/share`, for example?

I've though about two options so far:

- All users belonging to group `adm` CAN leave /home, or ...
- All users belonging to group `share` CANNOT leave /home.

How can I set that up using `setfacl`?

Comment: `setfacl` can't be used to jail users to a folder.

Comment: ok, thanks! ... and, is there any other way of doing so, that you know?

Comment: chroot jails, but that is not trivial to set up.

Comment: like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/609194/how-do-i-prevent-one-user-in-particular-from-accessing-my-home-directory And one with a bit more substance: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218430/using-acl-permissions-without-allowing-other-groups-to-access-a-directory