# How do i restrict user to make changes to NTFS partition ? (in easy steps)?

Tags: permissions, ntfs, restricted-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restrict access to a NTFS partition to a standard (non-admin) user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141139/how-to-restrict-access-to-a-ntfs-partition-to-a-standard-non-admin-user)

I have 5 NTFS partition on single hard disk where ubuntu is also installed. I want to restrict particular user to have only READ permission and wont make changes or delete anything on NTFS drives. Even want to restrict some folder's on NTFS parition to get access or hide from user. 
I can do it very well in Win7 but no idea how to in UBUNTU 12.04 ?

Also how can i grant access to NTFS partition to that user without password prompt ?

Yelp needed in advance configuration.

Comment: Any easy steps then the above link ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, mount the partitions you want to restrict. Then navigate to /media/ directory and note the mount pount (names where partitions has been mounted)

Fire up a terminal and execute the following commands -

**sudo blkid** - *note the UUID and sda number (/dev/sda'x') of the partition you want to keep restricted*

**sudo nano /etc/fstab**

And add the following at the end -

**/dev/sda'x'   /media/'mount point'   ntfs-3g noauto,uid=xxxxyyyy,unmask=7 0   0**

Comment: What will make this ? I want partition to be mounted automatically without asking for root password . and would restrict user from making changes to it even some folder to hide from him

Comment: For mounting disks automatically, check this link. **askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-hdds-mount-at-startup-in-ubuntu-12-04/165462#comment209447_165462**

Comment: OK @AkshitBaunthiyal but what about the command you have given what will it do ?

Comment: Just check the link I posted. Add the part after 'mount point in this post' to the command in the other post. It will automount the partition and restrict usage by other users.